# node-red, raspberry Pi and MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, raspberry-pi, node-red

I have an MSSQL instance running on a Windows host, and would like to have a Raspberry Pi running node-red save data to this database.

I've tried the node-red-contrib-mssql node and it seems to come close, but the SQL Server is refusing the connection, for one reason or the other depending on how I've set up the node. Most recent error is 'login failed for user mjmain/mpi'.

On the SQL side I've tried SQL/Mixed authentication, new logins, and configuring remote access through TCP, but I've had no luck.

Has anyone successfully used this node in this environment?

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you running on this Windows host?

Comment: 2008 R2 on WIndows 7 Professional

Comment: That is the version, what is the edition? Developer? Standard? Express? Something else? Depending on the edition, connections from other machines/devices may not be permitted.

Comment: Express with Advanced Services (64-bit) - version is 10.50.2500.0

Comment: Firewall on the Windows host on, or off? Port open?

Answer (score 1):

Just configured such setup today.
Node-Red on RPi, MS-SQL Express on Win7.

There are advices (all this on Window side)...
- enable TCP/IP Client Protocol in SQL Server Configuration Manager
- enable 1433 TCP port for incoming connection in Windows firewall (or disable the firewall)
- switch on and make run automaticly SQL Browser service (might be helpfull)

Make sure that server login is well mapped to the database user and has rights!
In Node-Red in connection parameters you need to use server login.
Other issue I had was DNS - so I am using IP_address_sql_server\instance_name.
Best regards